# Function to wait for a result of an asynchronous process in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I want to write a function which checks some result of asynchronous process by some condition which needs to be met. That function should use some maximum wait time, loop wait time and should iterate until condition is met.

The mixture of code and pseudo-code is as follows:

```
fun waitUntilConditionIsMatched() {
    val maximumWaitTime = Duration.ofSeconds(10L)
    val maximum = currentTimeMillis() + maximumWaitTime.toMillis()

    println("Waiting for maximum of $maximumWaitTime for a condition to be matched...")

    while (currentTimeMillis() <= maximum) {
        if (conditionIsMatched) {
            println("...condition matched")
            break
        } else {
            doWait(Duration.ofMillis(500))
        }
    }

    println("...timeout exceeded. Condition was not matched.")
}
```

Is there an idiomatic way how to write it in Kotlin?

Comment: Have you used runBlocking() ? Shall we use in ou code?

Answer (score 3):

You should look into [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html) which is pretty big branch of the language focused on asynchronous programming.

Sample application of what You mean in Kotlin (for JVM):

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

// dummy condition
var condition = false 

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // this code block is all that's needed to raise condition after half a second
    // without blocking current thread
    GlobalScope.launch{
        delay(500)
        println("condition ready")
        condition = true
    }

    // block the current thread while waiting for condition
    // this is required to use a suspend function
    val result = runBlocking{
        println("waiting for result started")
        waitForCondition(1000, 100)
    }
    println("condition was met:" + result)
}

// waits until condition is ready and return true when it is; otherwise returns false
// tailrec function gets rolled out into normal loop under the hood
suspend tailrec fun waitForCondition(maxDelay: Long, checkPeriod: Long) : Boolean{
    if(maxDelay < 0) return false
    if(condition) return true   
    delay(checkPeriod)  
    return waitForCondition(maxDelay - checkPeriod, checkPeriod)
}
```

Comment: Is it the correct way to use runBlocking ? Shall we use in production code ?

Comment: @Menu It can still be used i you absolutely need to block a thread but it's considered bad design. If you're using coroutines you should try to contain your asynchronous/suspending logic within a coroutine scope. Also this sample is a bit old, in newer Kotlin you can just declare `suspend fun main` and use `waitForCondition` directly in the body without the need of `runBlocking` .